# Meu programa para ver se 2 pontos num planos cartesiano estão perto ou longe

Tags: python-3.x

Estou fazendo o curso de python na coursera e tenho uma atividade que é pra eu saber se a distância entre dois pontos num plano cartesiano é maior ou menos que 10, quando coloco os numeros 0, 0, 11, 0. O programa dá a resposta errada

```
import math
x1 = int(input("Digite o primeiro número: "))
x2 = int(input("Digite o segundo número: "))
y1 = int(input("Digite o terceiro número: "))
y2 = int(input("Digite o quarto número: "))
ponto1 = (x1 - x2) ** 2
ponto2 = (y1 - y2) ** 2
math.sqrt(ponto1)
math.sqrt(ponto2)
if (ponto1 - ponto2) < 10:
    print("perto")
else:
    print("longe")
```

Comment: Acredito que você tenha que usar o valor absoluto da diferença: `if (abs(ponto1 - ponto2)) < 10:`

Answer (score 2):

Há um erro no cálculo:

**Calcular a raiz quadrada da *diferença* dos pontos e não da soma.**

Você também pode usar a função [hypot](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.hypot) que está presente no módulo `math` ou a função [dist](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/math.html#math.dist), que recebe duas sequências como argumentos em sua chamada, sendo cada sequência os números que representam os valores X e Y de cada vetor, nesse caso.

O resultado final do código seria algo como:

```
from math import sqrt, hypot, dist
x1 = int(input("Digite o primeiro número: "))
x2 = int(input("Digite o segundo número: "))
y1 = int(input("Digite o terceiro número: "))
y2 = int(input("Digite o quarto número: "))
ponto1 = (x2 - x1) ** 2
ponto2 = (y2 - y1) ** 2

resultado = sqrt(ponto1 + ponto2)
# Usando hypot:
# resultado = hypot(x2 - x1, y2 - y1)
# Ou usando dist
# resultado = dist((x2, x1), (y2, y1))

if resultado < 10:
    print("perto")
else:
    print("longe")
```

[Neste site](https://brasilescola.uol.com.br/matematica/distancia-entre-dois-pontos.htm) há uma explicação em português de como encontrar a distância entre dois pontos.

Comment: Acredito que o primeiro "erro" não é um erro, pois qualquer número elevado a uma potência par tem seu sinal sempre positivo, então não alteraria o resultado, daí não é um erro. Ex.: `(-3) ** 2 == 3 ** 2`.

Comment: Bem observado. Fiz uma edição no post para corrigir a resposta.

Comment: Muito bom @Ruan Montelo. Talvez seja util no futuro para quem ler sua resposta a informação de que  o módulo [*mat*](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/math.html#module-math) também possui a função [`math.dist(p, q)`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/math.html#math.dist) que retorna a distância euclidiana entre dois pontos p e q.

Comment: @AugustoVasques obrigado pela observação, alteração foi feita para complementar a resposta.